# Can I use Popen to interactively pass and read commands to the called process?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an interactive tool that run on console; when I run the tool, it waits for commands, executes them and when I am done, I type the `exit` command to quit.

I would like to use Python to pass commands to this interactive tool, and read the output; although I am having problems.

This is what I did so far:

```
proc = Popen(myapp, stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

This is opening my app and prints out the first line of output, but then even if I pass a write statement to `stdin`, nothing happens. If I would run this from terminal, I would get 4 lines before the prompt would show, but here I get just the first line.

```
proc.stdin.write('list\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

I tried to parse the lines based on the count, but I get a large number, while I should get just 3 lines; and after the counter passes the 3rd line, the app just hangs there doing nothing until I kill it.

```
total_lines = len(proc.stdout.readline()) # this returns me 300+ lines instead of 3
for lines in range(total_lines):
    print(proc.stdout.readline()) # when the counter passes 3, the app hangs
```

The idea is to pass different commands in sequence; kinda like what you would do in a regular shell, and read the output; although I can't get this to work. I don't get how you interact with this app; since it should work exactly like it does in terminal, but it does not.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Which Python version? What is the result of `proc.stdout.read()`? What is the result of `proc.stderr.read()`?

Comment: Hi, I am using OSX mainly, but would like to use this process also on Windows 10. As far as python, I use 3.7 currently but I can use the latest version if that add better support for this scenario. When I print the read function output I get nothing, the app just wait there without proceed further after that line. Same for stderr output. It looks like python is waiting for something. instead using readline I get at least something printed out.